# Angular passing object between parallel states

Tags: angularjs

what is possible way to pass user which I choose and catch in details view to parallel edit view ?

I catch 'selectedUser' in details view then I need to edit specific fields in edit view.

Below two parallel states.

```
$stateProvider.state('app.users.dealer.details', {
  resolve: {
    selectedUser: function ($stateParams, UserService) {
      var selectedUserId = $stateParams.userId;
      return UserService.get({userId: selectedUserId}).$promise;
    }
  },
  url: '/:userId',
  templateUrl: 'views/users/dealer-user-details.html',
  controller: 'UserCtrl'
});

$stateProvider.state('app.users.dealer.edit', {
  resolve: {
    selectedUser: function ($stateParams, UserService,selectedUser) {
      //var selectedUserId = $stateParams.userId;
      //return UserService.get({userId: selectedUserId}).$promise;
      return selectedUser;
    }
  },
  url:'/edit',
  templateUrl:'views/users/dealer-user-edit.html',
  controller: 'UserEditCtrl'
});
```

Parent state which contains list of users.

```
$stateProvider.state('app.users.dealer.list', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'views/users/dealer-users-list.html',
  controller: 'DealerUserListCtrl'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app.users.dealer.edit` has no information about `userId`. This view should either be a child of `app.users.dealer.details` to inherit it's parameters or declare `:userId` somethere in the url. Or both views could have a parent which knows about userId (has it in url template).